# Fitting fixed effects and random effects separately

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

```
mod <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|loc.id)) # a null model 
y1 <- resid(mod) # the residuals from the model
mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ x) # model the residuals as a function of x
mod1.predictions <- predict(mod) + predict(mod1) # this is the model which predicts `y` as a function of `x` while accounting for the effect of `loc.id`
```

mod is my null model and hence I am fitting a model that explains y just as a function of the intercept and the location. Then I used the left over variation in `y` to see if it is correlated with `x` i.e. after accounting for the effect of `loc.id`, I am examining  whether the residuals are correlated with the `x`.Then I predict the `residuals y` as a function of x and then add the prediction from the null model `mod1` to get my full predictions which is y predicting as a function of `x` and `loc.id`

I thought this is essentially the same as doing

```
 mod1 <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|loc.id))
 mod1.predictions <- predict(mod1)
```

Comment: Why do you think it's the same?

Comment: Okay. I have tried to explain more why I think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be the same because in the simple linear regression model you work with ordinary least squares, whereas in the mixed model with generalized least squares. The latter is affected by the estimated variance component for the random intercepts term for `loc.id`, and this will be different in the model

```
lmer(y ~ x + (1 | loc.id))
```

and in

```
lmer(y ~ 1 + (1 | loc.id))
```